# python-requests SSL Error; bad handshake; no ssl cipher list

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, python-requests

When trying to install some 3rd party apps with something like `pip install` or run apps that uses the `requests` module. I end up having this error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl_cipher_list_to_bytes', 'no ciphers available')],)",)
```

I didn't have this issue before. So I guess there's some conflict with the libraries. But I don't seem to get where the problem is coming from.

Comment: The error points to the fact that the requests module could not find a cipher suite that is common between your client and the server. But would need more information in order to fix this. Could you tell us which server are you connecting to? Are you restricting anything such as the tls version or the list of available cipher suites that requests can use?

Comment: @HussainAliAkbar It happens with any server actually I could try `requests.get('http://www.google.com')` and I would still get the same error. I don't think I'm restricting anything. but don't know how I could be sure.

Comment: Can you give me some more information as to how to reproduce this? Since doing just requests.get is returning 200 to me.